Milvus ConnectionRefusedError: how to connect locally
I am trying to run a RAG pipeline using haystack & Milvus.
Its my first time using Milvus, and I seem to have an issue with it.
I'm following this tutorial, with some basic changes: https://milvus.io/docs/integrate_with_haystack.md
Here is my code:
import os
import urllib.request

from haystack import Pipeline
from haystack.components.converters import MarkdownToDocument
from haystack_integrations.components.embedders.ollama import OllamaDocumentEmbedder, OllamaTextEmbedder

from haystack.components.preprocessors import DocumentSplitter
from haystack.components.writers import DocumentWriter

from milvus_haystack import MilvusDocumentStore
from milvus_haystack.milvus_embedding_retriever import MilvusEmbeddingRetriever

url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/7785/pg7785.txt"
file_path = "./davinci.txt"

if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path) 

document_store = MilvusDocumentStore(
    connection_args={"uri": "./milvus.db"},
    drop_old=True,
)

indexing_pipeline = Pipeline()
indexing_pipeline.add_component("converter", MarkdownToDocument())
indexing_pipeline.add_component(
    "splitter", DocumentSplitter(split_by="sentence", split_length=2)
)
indexing_pipeline.add_component("embedder", OllamaDocumentEmbedder())
indexing_pipeline.add_component("writer", DocumentWriter(document_store))
indexing_pipeline.connect("converter", "splitter")
indexing_pipeline.connect("splitter", "embedder")
indexing_pipeline.connect("embedder", "writer")

indexing_pipeline.draw('./pipeline_diagram.png')

indexing_pipeline.run({"converter": {"sources": [file_path]}})

It all works well until the last line, where I get a ConnectionRefusedError.
First the conversion (from markdown to document) runs well, but then the code fails.
I am not sure why it happens, as I see the milvus.db and milvus.db.lock files created as expected.
The full error is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:203, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    202 try:
--> 203     sock = connection.create_connection(
    204         (self._dns_host, self.port),
    205         self.timeout,
    206         source_address=self.source_address,
    207         socket_options=self.socket_options,
    208     )
    209 except socket.gaierror as e:

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:85, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     84 try:
---> 85     raise err
     86 finally:
     87     # Break explicitly a reference cycle

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:73, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     72     sock.bind(source_address)
---> 73 sock.connect(sa)
     74 # Break explicitly a reference cycle

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:791, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    790 # Make the request on the HTTPConnection object
--> 791 response = self._make_request(
    792     conn,
    793     method,
    794     url,
    795     timeout=timeout_obj,
    796     body=body,
    797     headers=headers,
    798     chunked=chunked,
    799     retries=retries,
    800     response_conn=response_conn,
    801     preload_content=preload_content,
    802     decode_content=decode_content,
    803     **response_kw,
    804 )
    806 # Everything went great!

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:497, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    496 try:
--> 497     conn.request(
    498         method,
    499         url,
    500         body=body,
    501         headers=headers,
    502         chunked=chunked,
    503         preload_content=preload_content,
    504         decode_content=decode_content,
    505         enforce_content_length=enforce_content_length,
    506     )
    508 # We are swallowing BrokenPipeError (errno.EPIPE) since the server is
    509 # legitimately able to close the connection after sending a valid response.
    510 # With this behaviour, the received response is still readable.

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:395, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, chunked, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    394     self.putheader(header, value)
--> 395 self.endheaders()
    397 # If we're given a body we start sending that in chunks.

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:1289, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1288     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1289 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:1048, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1047 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1048 self.send(msg)
   1050 if message_body is not None:
   1051 
   1052     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:986, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    985 if self.auto_open:
--> 986     self.connect()
    987 else:

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:243, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)
    242 def connect(self) -> None:
--> 243     self.sock = self._new_conn()
    244     if self._tunnel_host:
    245         # If we're tunneling it means we're connected to our proxy.

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:218, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    217 except OSError as e:
--> 218     raise NewConnectionError(
    219         self, f"Failed to establish a new connection: {e}"
    220     ) from e
    222 # Audit hooks are only available in Python 3.8+

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x30ca49690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:486, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    485 try:
--> 486     resp = conn.urlopen(
    487         method=request.method,
    488         url=url,
    489         body=request.body,
    490         headers=request.headers,
    491         redirect=False,
    492         assert_same_host=False,
    493         preload_content=False,
    494         decode_content=False,
    495         retries=self.max_retries,
    496         timeout=timeout,
    497         chunked=chunked,
    498     )
    500 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:845, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    843     new_e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", new_e)
--> 845 retries = retries.increment(
    846     method, url, error=new_e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    847 )
    848 retries.sleep()

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py:515, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    514     reason = error or ResponseError(cause)
--> 515     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    517 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=11434): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/embeddings (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x30ca49690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 1
----> 1 indexing_pipeline.run({"converter": {"sources": [file_path]}})
      3 print("Number of documents:", document_store.count_documents())

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/haystack/core/pipeline/pipeline.py:197, in Pipeline.run(self, data, debug, include_outputs_from)
    195 span.set_content_tag("haystack.component.input", last_inputs[name])
    196 logger.info("Running component {component_name}", component_name=name)
--> 197 res = comp.run(**last_inputs[name])
    198 self.graph.nodes[name]["visits"] += 1
    200 if not isinstance(res, Mapping):

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/haystack_integrations/components/embedders/ollama/document_embedder.py:139, in OllamaDocumentEmbedder.run(self, documents, generation_kwargs)
    136     raise TypeError(msg)
    138 texts_to_embed = self._prepare_texts_to_embed(documents=documents)
--> 139 embeddings, meta = self._embed_batch(
    140     texts_to_embed=texts_to_embed, batch_size=self.batch_size, generation_kwargs=generation_kwargs
    141 )
    143 for doc, emb in zip(documents, embeddings):
    144     doc.embedding = emb

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/haystack_integrations/components/embedders/ollama/document_embedder.py:107, in OllamaDocumentEmbedder._embed_batch(self, texts_to_embed, batch_size, generation_kwargs)
    105 batch = texts_to_embed[i]  # Single batch only
    106 payload = self._create_json_payload(batch, generation_kwargs)
--> 107 response = requests.post(url=self.url, json=payload, timeout=self.timeout)
    108 response.raise_for_status()
    109 result = response.json()

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py:115, in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    103 def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    104     r"""Sends a POST request.
    105 
    106     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
    112     :rtype: requests.Response
    113     """
--> 115     return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py:59, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     55 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     56 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     57 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     "timeout": timeout,
    586     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/haystack_milvus_playground/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:519, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    515     if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    516         # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
    517         raise SSLError(e, request=request)
--> 519     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    521 except ClosedPoolError as e:
    522     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=11434): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/embeddings (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x30ca49690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

any help resolving this would be appreciated. My assumption is that it is something very simple in creating the milvus database local connection, but I dont know where it is.

As suggested in earlier replies, Ollama was not running locally.
To resolve this I needed to:
1 - download and install Ollama
2 - pull (or run) in the terminal ollama pull nomic-embed-text for the embedders. This is not clear enough in the haystack documentation for the ollama integration but once this is done it should run.
Also I would suggest to change from:
indexing_pipeline.add_component("embedder", OllamaDocumentEmbedder())
to:
indexing_pipeline.add_component("embedder", OllamaDocumentEmbedder(model="nomic-embed-text", url="http://localhost:11434/api/embeddings")) 

Thanks for this answer which is almost right.
I am from the Haystack team and unfortunately, I just realized that our docs are wrong.
The default model is nomic-embed-text, which is a good embedding model. Instead, orca-mini is a generative model and does not produce good embeddings.
Could you please update the answer? I will take care of docs...

looks like OLLAMA embedding failed, you can try to check your ollama servie is normal, or just change to another embedding

This requires Milvus Lite and PyMilvus be very recent versions.  What version are you running?
https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-haystack
https://haystack.deepset.ai/integrations/milvus-document-store
Which operating system are you running?
I am running
pymilvus-2.4.4
milvus-haystack-0.0.8
haystack-ai-2.2.3

haystack-ai==2.2.3 ; pymilvus==2.4.4; milvus-haystack==0.0.8.  Im running it on a mac (silicon) on vscode in a conda environemnt.

Looks like OLLAMA is not running.  The embedding model is running on ollama and the request is timing out
you can tell from the stack trace:
--> 107 response = requests.post(url=self.url, json=payload, timeout=self.timeout)
